# Pairing two different brands of RAM... (Same speed, same CL16, different timing)

Tags: memory

So I have two kinds of ram sticks on my PC.
Both are 3200mhz DDR - CL16. But, the new pair is not the same timing.

I have assumed the modules would run at the same timing, speed, but something seems a bit off.
The first 2 modules: `BLS16G4D32AESB.M16FE` - Crucial
The second 2 modules: `F4-3200C16-16GVK` - G.Skill

Tried to run a few games, applications, did not experience critical issues. No BSOD. But occasionally, I get a "memory could not be read" issue. This happened in ASUS Armoury Crate and FileZilla's FTP server UI.

If I check CPU-Z, I see some weird information about the modules.

Ps.: The reason I had to go with these other modules is that no store has the original stick in the store anymore. The only advice I received was that I should get modules with the same speed, timing. So I did that. (I could not find modules that would match the timing exactly.)

I have posted the ram specs from HWINFO: https://pastebin.com/v44MvrFd

[image: CPU-Z-modules]

Comment: The faster memory is downclocking to the slower speed,   Have you confirmed that all of your memory is running at 1333.3 MHz @ 19-19-19-43?

Comment: You are also mixing dual and single rank memory. Not sure how critical that is though...

Comment: @Mokubai - Yeah I saw that but I don't know why CPU-Z is saying that. I installed the Crucial DIMM modules in the slot B2-A2. As stated on the motherboard and in the manual. https://i.imgur.com/aK3h2he.png And I put the new modules into B1-A1. || So. `[ G.Skill (new) | Crucial (old) | G.Skill (new) | Crucial (old) ]`

Comment: Dual rank is a feature of the memory stick. It's not the same as dual channel. https://uk.crucial.com/support/articles-faq-memory/what-is-a-memory-rank

Comment: Oh, shoot, yeah, never mind. Sorry, that was a brainfart moment. I totally thought it was about dual-channel and I was contemplating how I will take apart the whole PC again. I like air cooling but damn is it a hassle to add/remove components.